# ANTLR V4 Java Grammar shift operators

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I am working with the ANTLR v4 Java grammar available on github.

I have a question about something I saw in a particular rule : the shift operators. These operators are declared as follows :

```
('<' '<' | '>' '>' '>' | '>' '>')
```

I guess they are not declared like

```
('<<' | '>>>' | '>>')
```

because of what may occur with generic type declarations, as in

```
class C<T extends I<T>>
```

The final >> would be lexed as a shift operator. Am I right ? Now what I wonder is : does this notation '<' '<' allows white space to appear between the two "less than" signs ?

```
int a = 1 < < 2;
```

This would be a valid input ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parser would accept `1 < < 2` as an expression, but a listener executed after the parse tree is produced would check each instance of a shift operator in the parse tree to ensure that the node was actually the result of the correct operator used in the source code.

```
@Override
public void enterShiftOperator(ShiftOperatorContext ctx) {
  for (int i = 1; i < ctx.getChildCount(); i++) {
    if (ctx.getChild(i).getTokenIndex() != ctx.getChild(i - 1).getTokenIndex() + 1) {
      throw new UnsupportedOperationException("TODO: report error about incorrect operator in the source code");
    }
  }
}
```

**Notes:**

- This implementation relies on the grammar not using the `-> skip` lexer command, because doing so would impact the indexes assigned to tokens.
- This implementation doesn't check the text directly because [`JavaUnicodeInputStream`](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/tool/test/org/antlr/v4/test/JavaUnicodeInputStream.java) doesn't implement Unicode translation for the `getText()` method.

Comment: Thank you Sam, I get it. I am adding generics support for my java grammar, and was having problems with shift tokens ('>>'). If I split the token as described above it is ok, except that I have to split also shift assignment operators ('>>=' have to become '>' '>' '='), and I don't get this. Why the assignment operator is giving me problems ?